# How to limit scope of re-rendering to single component in React?

Tags: reactjs

My components are structured looks like this. Each component is it's own functional component in its own file - this is just a schematic of how they interract.

```
<FirstLevelComponent>
    // propValue is declared on this level with useState hook.
    <SecondLevelComponent someProp={propValue}> 
        <ChildComponent1></ChildComponent1>
        <ChildComponent2 someProp={propValue}></ChildComponent2>
        <ChildComponent3></ChildComponent3>
    </SecondLevelComponent>
</FirstLevelComponent>
```

`someProp` is declared in state in the `FirstLevelComponent` and is passed along to the `SecondLevelComponent` and when it changes, it triggers the re-render of the entire `SecondLevelComponent`. But the only dependency on that prop is in one of the children. The rest of the children are unaffected.

What would be the best way to isolate that behavior and only limit scope of re-rendering to the single child that depends on that prop?

**Some constraints:**

1. This is a huge production application so something like `Just add redux` would not be an easy solution.
2. Refactoring `SecondLevelComponent` will be a challenge (1500 lines of code), while I am open to such opportunity`, I am looking for the way to achieve this assuming it's not a hello world project. Solutions that are easy and ideal for application in its early stages are quite a rework when we are dealing with legacy code.

Comment: I would have to do some testing but you could try to wrap your child components in `useCallback` to prevent them from re-rendering, however not sure if that will work since React is going to re-render parent component and everything in it, but worth a shot to see if `useCallback` would prevent child from re-rendering.

Comment: useCallback and useMemo will keep the child from rerendering when parent state updates. Not vice versa @Drew

Answer (score 0):

**and only limit scope of re-rendering to the single child that depends on that prop?**

What you're looking to accomplish goes against the nature of React. If a parent component has state, and that state changes, React will react and rerender the component.

Stopping the parent component from rerendering when its state changes is an anti pattern (as opposed to simply stopping its children from rerendering with `useMemo`).

The way I see it, you have the following options:

1. Add state to the child component instead. If it's the only component reliant on this state, it should be a simple refactor.
2. Replace useState with useRef in the parent component. Pass this to the child for creating initial state.

Option two could lead to other implications if anything else in the app is dependant on this piece of state.

Now, if you just want to keep the extra children from rerendering, which isn't exactly what I quoted above from the question, you could just simply use `useMemo` (and `useCallback` if passing a function as a prop)..

Comment: Definitely not looking to implement an antipattern. Normally I would use a Context or  Redux for such an application, but this is legacy code and the less I change the better.

It just strikes me how silly the design of this app is that because of one single prop that is passed downwards all other children re-render, and we have 132 components in that monster <SecondLevelComponent>. You can see how our app re-renders just for that one prop.

Comment: @Alexus are you only concerned with the other _children_ re-rendering? If so, `useMemo` will solve this issue no prob, as I stated at the end of my answer.

Comment: Only problem, we have 132 other children. So I would have to add useMemo for every single one of them or there is a way to wrap them all into a single block? @silencedogood

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem, also big application

### Option 1

You can take advantage of render from React composition if you can move `propValue` state and `ChildComponent2` component  into `SecondLevelComponent`

Explanation: the states in SecondLevelComponent wont rerender his childs like `ChildComponent1` and `ChildComponent3`

### Option 2

You can memoize you components using React.useMemo not React.memo because you are not passing `propValue` in `ChildComponent1` and `ChildComponent3` like this:

```
// How to memoize
const ChildComponent1Memoized = React.useMemo(()=><ChildComponent1/>,[propValue])
```

```
// In this case ChildComponent1Memoized will not rerender again
<SecondLevelComponent someProp={propValue}> 
    {ChildComponent1Memoized} // <---
    <ChildComponent2 someProp={propValue}></ChildComponent2>
    <ChildComponent3></ChildComponent3>
</SecondLevelComponent>
```

#### Extra

if you are passing functions as props be sure you are using useCallbak in every function, because they are rebuilding in every render, that cause Memo dosent work